# Swiftfox without the file, view toolbar

Tags: firefox, menu

Is there a way to remove the File, Edit, View... toolbar from Firefox (so that I will have only the address toolbar visible)?
I think in Windows from version 3.5 you can just right click on the toolbar and you can just  unselect it...
I don't have Firefox installed, i use Swiftfox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Hide Menubar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4762/) addon. The menubar is hidden by default but you can toggle it with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [tiny menu extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1455/) to reduce the menu bar to an icon next to my address bar.
[image: The back/forward/stop buttons are all hidden when not needed]

Otherwise, you should be able to create a new toolbar and drag the menu bar onto it, then hide that toolbar.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried it. My problem is that it doesn't let me place the back/forward button at the very left and that is a real problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Tiny Menu extension in the past, but now I use Compact Menu 2. It works like a charm and you can put the menu anywhere.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4550/